# Turning a string into an array of integers jython

Tags: python, arrays, string, integer, jython

```
def convertToInteger(stringID):
  id = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I need to use a parameter `stringID` and convert it into the array `id` in Integer form.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please explain with a sample input and output?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
stringId = '0123456'
[int(x) for x in stringId]
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Or alternatively, using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
map(int, stringId)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```